# Copy files with a certain extension into a folder

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I want to find all the PDF files from the computer and put them into a folder.

So far, I have this:

```
mkdir d:\test
chcp 65001
d:
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b  *.pdf') DO copy "%%a" d:\test\
c:
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b  *.pdf') DO copy "%%a" d:\test\
f:
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b  *.pdf') DO copy "%%a" d:\test\
```

For some reason, it doesn't copy everything. In D:, it copied 2126 files out of 2400, and in F: it copied 274 out of 284.

Any ideas why some PDF files aren't being copied and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can count the files and so check for duplicates:

```
md d:\test 2>nul
set /a count=0
set /a dupli=0
for /r "d:\" %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    if not exist "d:\test\%%~nxi" (
        copy "%%~fi" "d:\test\%%~nxi"
        set /a count+=1
    ) else set /a dupli+=1
)
echo %count% files copied,  %dupli% not (duplicate files).
```

Put the target folder in an other drive to avoid copying to itself.

Comment: Thank you mate for your time ,i run this for the F still the same result it copies only 274 out of 284 as for the D i noticed that the pc does a beep noise for a few seconds also it doesnt copy everything it copies 2126  out of 2481(the numbers are the same as in my program).I forgot a detail which i dont know if its important some of the pdfs dont have english characters, their names are written in another language that's why i put the chcp 65001.it helped greatly before i put it it wasn't copying around 1200 files with it it doesnt copy around 350

Comment: You need a script, that renames the duplicate files before copying. The chcp shouldn't play a role

Comment: rename them before i start copying or as i do the copy?

Comment: You can do it before or you can use a script, that does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not having alot of details, my first guess would be that there are duplicate file names.  Copy in a acript will not prompt for overwrite and will skip the file.

Comment: The thing is i want even the duplicates cause in some cases its different pdf with the same name for example 1.pdf its common

Comment: As this is the case, Endoo provided a great starting point.  When you detect that there is a dupliate, you will need a scripted process to copy as a new unique file name.  If you have many files with the same name, make sure the process really chooses a unique name or re-checks for an existing file with the same name (with a loop perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this happens because you're not in the right folder when executing the FOR command.

Executing

```
D:
```

just changes the drive, but not the directory. If the last used directory of the D drive was `D:\Example`, there's where the command takes you.

There are three ways to fix this:

- Execute

  ```
  D:
  CD \
  ```

  before the FOR command.
- Execute

  ```
  CD /D D:\
  ```

  before the FOR command.
- Specify the drive and directory in the FOR command itself:

  ```
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('DIR /S /B  D:\*.pdf') DO COPY "%%A" D:\test\
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your help mate but unfortunately nothing changed still the same result with all the 3 ways :(